# "used to" for past habitual: analysis

Tags: english, grammar, morphosyntax

I teach ESL at the adult level.  I am trying to analyze "used to" for past habitual, as in:

- My car used to malfunction a lot.

Is "used to" an adverb-phrase meaning something like 'for a long time in the past'?  Or is it a finite verb?

If it's an adverb-phrase, it's worth noting that we don't have a past-tense main verb, as:

- My car used to malfunctioned(sic) a lot.

Perhaps that's evidence that "used to" is actually a finite verb?

I believe I may have read somewhere that "used to" evolved from "was/were used to" (meaning 'was/were accustomed to'); however, if this be the case, then I would expect a gerund instead of a base infinitive, as:

- My car used to malfunctioning(sic) a lot.

I'll appreciate any insights.

Comment: _Used to_ is an idiom; in fact, there are [two idioms pronounced alike](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/67251/15299) but with different syntax and meaning. This one is a [past tense construction with special presuppositions](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83557/15299). It's very common in speech, but in writing it's not used as often because there's [a certain confusion about the past negative spelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/314973/15299): "didn't used to" or "didn't use to"; neither one feels good. But then English spelling sucks, as everybody knows.

Comment: If we're going to say that "used to" is actually the finite verb in the sentence, and if we're going to say that the "-ed" makes it past, then it seems we would want to write "didn't use to" (with no D).  On the other hand, if we're going to say that the "-ed" is something else, like the participle/adjective "-ed" in "accustomed to", then it should _not_ come off when we use aux. "did".  But if that were the case, then we wouldn't use "did" as the aux; we'd use "was/were".  This makes it appear to me that "used to" is likely the finite verb.

Comment: I'm not sure whether _used to_ should be considered finite or not. It doesn't inflect worth a damn; rather, it's got the same kind of tense as modal auxiliaries and their periphrastic equivalents -- _hafta, gonna, wanna, oughta, gotta,_ and their ilk. Except it triggers _Did_-Insertion with negative contractions.

Comment: @jlawler Yes I agree, it's probably best written as _usta_. And re the negative, there's also the other form _usen't_.

Comment: Not for American speakers there isn't.

Comment: Why is everybody making this so complicated? It seems to me to be a simple past tense verb (used) with an infinitive (to malfunction). No different from *tended to malfunction* or *needed to malfunction*. In this case *use* means "to be accustomed to or in the habit of." We just confine its use to past tense, except for in the negative, and always combine it with an infinitive.

Comment: @ Tom: The fact that it's confined to past seems worth remarking upon (unlike "tend" or "need").  If it means 'habitually' or 'for a long time', I should be able to remove the "-ed", and use it in other tenses (I'll use to(sic) hike in the desert when I move to Phoenix).  In addition, "use" does not normally mean 'do habitually'.  What I'm especially trying to determine is whether the "-ed" endows the 'past' to it, or whether 'past' is innate to it, and the "-ed" is something else, like a participle.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion about "use". I've popped in a proper answer which you may find useful.

Comment: "used to" is a phrasal modal, an auxiliary. This is an often-overlooked part of  English grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Preliminary point: The verb-form is the single word "used", not *"used to". Take your example:

***My car used [to malfunction a lot].***

The bracketed sequence is a non-finite clause acting as complement to "used". "To" belongs in the complement clause; it's simply a marker, a subordinator whose function is to mark *to*-infinitival clauses.

No, it’s not an adverb phrase. The 'main' verb is the auxiliary verb "used"; it’s a tensed verb-form, more specifically a past tense form. Auxiliaries are primary (tensed) verb-forms, for example “might”, “could” and “should” are respectively the past tense forms of the present tense forms “may”, “can” and “shall”. Note, incidentally, that although “use” is an auxiliary, it is semantically quite distinct from the modal auxiliaries; the meaning it expresses is aspectual, not modal.

“Use” is highly defective; it has no present tense, only infinitival and past forms, so although the form “use” appears to be a present tense form, it is in fact the infinitival form which is only used in negatives and with inversion: *He didn’t use to smoke*; *Did he use to smoke*?

There is the added complication that “use” can be a lexical verb or an auxiliary one, though the books tell us that many speakers treat it as a lexical verb. I suspect that’s due to the unacceptability for many people of the auxiliary use found in %*Smoking usedn’t to be allowed* and %*Used he to smoke?*

**Lexical Use** (infinitival verb-form + do-support required in negatives and questions):

*He used to smoke*. *He didn’t use to smoke*. *Did he use to smoke?*

**Auxiliary Use** (past tense verb-form, no do-support required)

*He used to smoke*. %*He usedn’t to smoke*. %*Used he to smoke*?

(% = acceptable in some dialects only)

Comment: Is there any literature which would classify "use" as an auxiliary? As far as I understood auxiliary verbs, they are "helper verbs" to construct complex tenses, in English this would be "be", "have" and in some contexts "do", but I wouldn't think that any verb could be an auxiliary simply because it has restricted grammatical use and selects an infinitive verb phrase as an argument. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I haven't seen a definition of auxiliaries so far that would support classifying "use" as one.

Comment: Okay, so I just thought about it again and it might be that we have different definitoins of "auxiliary" in mind. To me, "auxiliary" was restricted to the verbs helping to build complex tenses, therefore in English restricted to "be", "have", "do", possibly "would" (like in "He would always leave the stove on"), which are obviously distinct from the modal verbs like "can", "must" etc, which are not only semantically different but also have only a finite form (* "to can") and express solely modality, or similar types of such verbs expressing, e.g., aspect.

Comment: But one might also take "auxiliary" as the general term for all types of such verbs, including both the tense auxiliaries and modal, aspectual, ... verbs, so in that sense one could probably indeed regard "use" as one of those auxiliary verbs, more precisely an aspectual one, as you said. I'm not sure now what the most widely accepted terminlogical distribution between those verbs is; do you have any literature in mind that I could hopefully safely rely on?

Comment: @lemontree In most modern English academic grammars auxiliaries are verbs which display [NICE properties](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189). Of course some verbs at the fringes - such as *used* don't do all of those but just some of them, and only some of the time ...

Comment: I can't remember all the literature on this that I read when I was doing my masters, but it's hard to argue definitively that *used* has a plain form and also that it has past tense. Why? Because for many speakers at least the *use* that's written in *Did he use(d) always to do that* still has a /t/ at the end when spoken.  So if we disregard the 'conventional' spelling', which is often ignored, and which could be argued to just be an attempt to pull *used to* into line with other verbs, the 'past tense' and plain form are the same ...

Comment: Or perhaps what I'm trying to say is that the idea that the spoken *use(d)* which comes after DO support has some kind of *past tense* morphology knocked off it, is hard to argue for.

Comment: Oops, forgot the +1

Comment: @lemontree It can be both a lexical verb and an auxiliary one. It’s not actually a modal auxiliary (it’s aspectual), but as an auxiliary, it behaves in some respects like the prototypical modals in that it requires a bare infinitival complement and it has no present or past participle forms. And it has a couple of the usual auxiliary properties like primary verb negation and a reduced form. But perhaps most tellingly, it inverts with the subject to form interrogatives: _He used to smoke_ ~ _Used he to smoke?_. Only auxiliary verbs invert like that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd point out that *use* in this sense began life as a lexical verb - you find it fully inflected for instance in the AV "Look thou upon me, and be merciful unto me, as thou usest to do unto those that love thy name," and this persists into the 19th century. I suggest that the anomalies and quarrels over negative and interrogative forms are effects of its (still incomplete) evolution from lexical to quasi-modal; *hafta* exhibits the same conflicts. Perhaps we should call these "Hunchback" verbs! :)

Comment: @Araucaria I wouldn’t go along with that. In construction with auxiliary “do” as in _Did he use to live alone?_ “use” can only be the plain form, but that’s the only place it’s found.  And “used” is clearly an inflected form of “use” to give the past tense. The uncertainty about the form of the past tense, as in _He use**d** to smoke_ probably arises because (as you allude to) “used to” is pronounced with a single /t/ and hence is homophonous with the “use to” in _He didn’t use to smoke_.

Comment: @StoneyB As I said in my answer, for some speakers, "use" is a lexical verb; thus for others it's an auxiliary verb. The main difference lies in whether you're comfortable with the auxiliary use in examples like _Used you to live near there?_ and _It usedn't to be allowed_. If you're not, then just use the lexical equivalent with do-support for interrogatives and negatives: _Did you use to live near there?_ and _It didn't use to be allowed_. I don't see the evolution that you talk of; if anything it's the other way round, with an increasing number of speakers treating it as a lexical verb.

Comment: Incidentally, for those who resent the criticism being levelled at "use" for having dual status as both a lexical verb and an auxiliary one, there's some comfort to be had from the fact that "use" is not alone; for example "need", "dare" and static "have" can all be auxiliary and lexical, though they have their individual peculiarities.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I *think* I implied in my rambling comment that I was backtracking. But what I *was* saying in the end is that there is no way of thinking that there is any past tense *morphology* in the spoken word (or in the grammar) which is missing from the plain form but present in the .preterite. My point is that the writing is useless presrciptivism. In my example, you'll notice that *use(d)* occurs before a vowel, but still has /t/. So how can wee decide that it's the verb /ju:z/? The plain form has a /t/!

Comment: @Araucaria Hold on! So there's a homophony issue; so what, we know that. It doesn't matter. 'Facts is facts', as they say, and the tests show clearly the contrast in the syntax of  aux "use" vs lexical "use". You're over-analysing.

Comment: @BillJ  I'm not disagreeing with you! (apart from perhaps just very minimally, I don't think use is a good representation of the plain form in writing - it's been largely ignored even in published books, where didn't used is reasonably common, but that has nothing directly or pointedly to do with anything you wrote, it was more of an observation).

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion**; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41130/discussion-on-answer-by-billj-used-to-for-past-habitual-analysis).

Comment: @StoneyB: Which verse is this ("Look thou upon me, and be merciful unto me, as thou usest to do unto those that love thy name,")?  It's an interesting piece of evidence.  I take it to mean 'as thou usually doest', in other words present-tense.  It may be a critical piece of evidence in understanding the development of "used to".

Comment: @Araucaria: "Did he use(d) always to do that still has a /t/ at the end when spoken": I consider this critical evidence.  It's the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @PaulLNewJr Ps 119:32. But you need go no further than [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/472/mode/2up), s.v. **use**, *v*, **V.** *intr.* **19** and **20**, which will supply citations stretching back to the 14th century.

Comment: @BillJ: "The verb-form is the single word "used", not *"used to". Take your example: My car used [to malfunction a lot]."  Would you analyze "have to" the same way?  I see a meaning-difference between "used" vs. "used to" (and "have" vs. "have to") that doesn't seem predictable, seeming to argue for a re-analysis of "used to" (and "have to") as phrases.

Comment: @StoneyB: fascinating -- exactly the kind of information I was after!

Comment: @Paul L New Jr I suspect the reason that people consider “to” + “use/have” as a unit is that they are commonly used as ellipted forms of the full VP, e.g. A: “Do I really have to go the dentist”?, B: “Yes, you have to__”. Similarly, A: “Do you smoke”? B: “No, but I used to__”. In those examples, the gaps represent the ellipted words “go ” and “smoke”. But I don’t think the frequent use of such ellipsis warrants “used to” and “have to” being reanalysed as verbal idioms taking bare infinitival complements.

Comment: @BillJ.  It's an interesting subject, and one that I've been thinking about for over 20 years.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this should be an adverb phrase.

Of course, the construction is highly conventionalised, probably even lexicalised and no longer productive (you probably couldn't say *My car uses to malfuction a lot*), but syntactically, this is a perfectly valid past tense verb which takes a verb in bare infinitive as an argument (this is why * *used to malfunctioned* or * *used to malfunctioning* is ungrammatical).
If it were an adverb phrase, what would be the finite verb in the sentence then? There needs to be one, and certainly this is *used (to)*, due to its inflection, due to its syntactic position which is the usual default position for finite verbs and due to there not being any other possibilty to find a finite verb in the sentence, without which it would definitely be ungrammatical.

What would your arguments in favour of it being an *adverb phrase* be? I don't see any similarity with an AP here; *used to* isn't anything that modifies a averb, but is a verb itself; also, I know of no case where an AP could take a verb complex in bare infinitive as an argument (which *used to* does), in general adjunctions can not have any arguments (that *malfunction* is an obligatory argument of *used to* gets clear when we remove it and get an ungrammatical sentence: * *My car used to*); and most importantly, an adverb phrase would be merged into the syntax tree by adjunction, i.e. it would be an optional constituent which just modifies some other constituent (in case of adverbs, this is mostly the verbal phrase) but can easily be left out without this changing the grammaticality of the sentence (*My car used to malfunction* vs. * *My car malfuction a lot*).
This may hold true for *a lot*, but in the use of *used to*, this is definitely not the case, this is not just some adjunction that merely modifies its core constituents, but an a core contituent itself, namely the VP.

So I really don't think *used to* could in any way be analysed as an adverb phrase, and I don't see the problem of it being analysed as a finite verb, only because its use is in some way restricted and more or less lexicalised.

Update:
I must revise my claim that *used to* is not productive: *I use to play tennis on modays* is perfectly fine, and the fact that the full inflection paradigm is possible and regular (*I use to, you use to, he uses to, ..., I used to, you used to, ...*) I would see as another argument that *used to* is a totally normal finite verb, just in this context to some degree lexicalised/conventionalised and usually used in past tense.

Update 2:
The native speakers here have convinced me that my grammaticality judgement about present tense is probably wrong ;) So this doesn't seem to count as an argument for *used to* being a fully productive verb; but still, the other factors I mentioned are sufficient evidence in my opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't think that "he uses to play tennis" is at all grammatical

Comment: It sounds a little weirder than *he used to* to me as well (this is why I first thought it can't be used with present tense), but I don't think it's ungrammatical, especially because the same sentence in first person sounds totally natural to me, so I would think *He uses to play tennis* is not wrong. I'm not a native speaker however.

Comment: I'm not sure the present tense is grammatical either, I think it might just be the past tense suffix getting dropped in less formal speech. If you can show an example of "he uses to" or get another native speaker to affirm it then maybe, but for now I'd have to say you're wrong. (It could perhaps be grammatical in another dialect, but I doubt it. I don't think I've ever heard it in any dialect.)

Comment: Google gives me 612.00 results for "he uses to", 541.000 for "she uses to" , 718.000 for "it uses to" and 178.000 for "one uses to" (phrase put between quotes in the search so it actually searches for the whole expression).
I think if the phrase *use-PRES.3SG* were ungrammatical, there should be significantly less than a total of 2.049.000 results - although, again, I agree that it sounds a little less natural than the other setnences.

Comment: I think I remember that I learnt "use to" for expressing habits also in present in school, but it's some time ago, might be that I'm wrong ;)

Comment: Almost all of those are relative clauses using the normal sense of use (to utilise). They're not at all comparable. And if you're not a fluent speaker, then sorry, but you're really not qualified to judge its naturalness. :)

Comment: The fact that "I used to play tennis" is **pronounced** like it was spelled "I use to play tennis" -- the /z/ changes to /s/ in the idiom -- is a bug in the spelling system that also produces the aversion to the written past negative "I didn't use(d) to", in either spelling.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I don't think it's even accurate to say the past tense marker is dropped. It just looses its voicing: [just tu]. And then the ts join together, but it gets spelt as "use to" because, as normal, English spelling is unphonetic ;)

Comment: Quick judgement from a native speaker (New Zealand): "You're making me think hard about this. I say this often but barely write it." (mostly refering to the first person use though). So it seems to be less common then past tense, but maybe not completely ungrammatical.

Comment: @jlawler Your remark on the phonological influence is a good point, probably this plays a role too. 
I just realised that there may be another reason why present tense is not that acceptable - it may be due to the interaction between different grammatical constructions available: For repeated events or habits in the past, there is no way around using "used to", but for habits in the present, you would probably simply use simple present (*I play tennis every morning* is unambiguous with respect to whether this is being a habit-like event or an event currently going on, where you would...

Comment: ... otherwise say *I am playing tennis*), while this grammatical distinction is not available for past events, where the usage of past tense (more moment-like event, but not habit-like) vs. progressive forms (ongoing event) is semantically different. So probably you just don't really need to use *use to* in present tense because the distinction is already made clear by choosing simple present over present progressive.

Comment: @curiousdannii That I am not a *native* speaker doesn't automatically mean I'm not *fluent*; although my English may not be excellent enough to not make any mistakes, I speak, hear, write and read almost exclusively English in the context of my studies and work, and after permanently being exposed to English for years, I think I can allow myself to evaluate what sounds normal and frequent to me and what less.

Comment: My cursory glance at the examples of "she uses to" at Google comes up with 2 possibilities: (1) it means 'she uses in order to' (a different meaning), or (2) they were other people just like us discussing this topic!

Comment: The evidence at present (lack of past-tense marking in the main verb) points to "used to" as the finite verb.  The only question in my mind now is why have so many teachers and textbooks taught NEVER to take the D off (even w/ aux "did")?  Could that point-out some intuition that "used to" is something other than a finite, past-tense verb?  Perhaps the fact that "used to" is only used in the past explains our perception of it as idiomatic, as something other than a past-tense verb, but perhaps, nonetheless, that is all it is.

Comment: I suggest that @jlawler is right that maybe it's best thought of as another modal auxiliary verb. BTW, as an English native speaker (Australian), something like 'he uses to play tennis' is _completely_ unacceptable for me.

Comment: Not really modal -- no modality in involved. Instead, it's a complex aspect -- asserted true in the past but presupposed false in the present. In some ways the opposite of _not...any more_, which asserts falsity in the present but presupposes truth in the past.

Comment: @lemontree I didn't mean to offend you, which is why I wrote *if* you're not a fluent speaker. Your writing here is definitely consistently very good! but still, my native speaker intuitions say the present tense *uses to* is just not grammatical at all.

Comment: @curiousdannii Okay, wasn't sure on how to interpret your comment, maybe my reaction was too harsh then. Of course I agree with you that native speaker judgements are more reliable than the ones by speakers who only know English as a second language.

Comment: Apparently, "used to" can only be used in the past.  For example, this sentence would be ungrammatical: "When I move to Phoenix in the fall, I'll use to(sic) hike in the desert".  Even though I removed the "-ed", it's still no good.  Is this evidence that the semantics 'past' must reside in the expression itself, not in the "-ed"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; you can continue this conversation [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41070/discussion-on-answer-by-lemontree-used-to-for-past-habitual-analysis).